# Handle JSON serialization in Jboss EAP 7.2.0.GA

Tags: java, json, jboss, jax-rs

In my Jboss, I try to implement a REST service using JAX-RS. It should return the JSON serialized version of some object

```java
 @GET
  @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
  public BlacklistDTO getByName(
      @QueryParam("gav") final List<String> gavStringList)
  {
     ...
  }
```

Some parts of the object are not correctly serialized (the result is empty). How can I handle/customize the way JSON is generated by Jboss?

Comment: Hi, is your application using CDI ? do you use Jackson to convert to JSON? do you use Resteasy?

Comment: How do I find out? I am running a Jboss and this is probably configured _somewhere_, but not in my code or my `pom.xml`.

Comment: Usually you have a CDI descriptor, beans.xml in META-INF/beans.xml or WEB-INF/beans.xml. This activate CDI in your environment. Resteasy is the default implementation of jax-rs in Jboss/EAP, and EAP v7.4.0 is using Resteasy v3.5.0 (https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.5.0.Final/userguide/html_single). Check your pom.xml it will be including eg. a resteasy-jackson2-provider or a resteasy-jettison-provider to determine what json provider are you using (or check your stacktrace in debug mode)

Comment: You need to show the structure of your `BlacklistDTO` and present a sample of the JSON that you're expecting to be produced. Right now I don't think CDI has anything to do with your problem.

Comment: Sorry for answering late. My POM just references `javaee-api`, I do not have any resources in the project. I do not know whether CDI, Jackson or Resteasy is involved in the process but it would interesting to find out.

Answer (score 6):

You can customize the configuration of your utility to serialize / deserialize JSON (usually Jackson that is included in EAP) and configure / register modules to Jackson that indicate how to perform this work on complex objects.

If you are using CDI + Resteasy + Jackson you can do:

1. Provide a JAX-RS Custom Json Provider where you can configure your Jackson ObjectMapper with your custom configuration.. eg.

   ```
   @Provider
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public class CustomJsonProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
   private final ObjectMapper mapper;

   public CustomJsonProvider() {
       ObjectMapper mapperCdi = null;
       //if you are using CDI and you have your own Custom Object Mapper...
       BeanManager bm = CDI.current().getBeanManager();
       Set<Bean<?>> sBeans = bm.getBeans(ObjectMapper.class);
       if (sBeans != null && !sBeans.isEmpty()) {
           @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
           Bean<ObjectMapper> bean = (Bean<ObjectMapper>) sBeans.iterator().next();
           CreationalContext<ObjectMapper> ctx = bm.createCreationalContext(bean);
           mapperCdi = (ObjectMapper) bm.getReference(bean, ObjectMapper.class, ctx);
       }
       if (mapperCdi != null) {
           mapper = mapperCdi;
       }else {
       //if you are not using CDI, you can create your own Custom Object Mapper or get it from a factory e.g you can do here AppConfig.getObjectMapperInstance() or create a new one
           mapper = new ObjectMapper();
           //eg. configuration of Hibernate 5 - Jackson Module
           Hibernate5Module h5m = new Hibernate5Module();
           h5m.configure(Hibernate5Module.Feature.SERIALIZE_IDENTIFIER_FOR_LAZY_NOT_LOADED_OBJECTS, true);
           mapper.registerModule((com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module) h5m);

           mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
                   .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true);
           mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);

           //eg. custom Jackson SimpleModule registration
           SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("PaginationModule") {
               private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

               @Override
               public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
                   context.addAbstractTypeResolver(
                           new SimpleAbstractTypeResolver().addMapping(Slice.class, SliceClientImpl.class));
                   context.addAbstractTypeResolver(
                           new SimpleAbstractTypeResolver().addMapping(Page.class, PageClientImpl.class));
               }
           };
           mapper.registerModule(module);
       }
   }

   @Override
   public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
       return mapper;
   }
   }
   ```
2. If you are using CDI define your 'producer' method (@Produce) and your Jackson ObjectMapper factory:

   ```
   @ApplicationScoped
   public class AppConfig {
   private static ObjectMapper objectMapper;
   // Jackson Object Mapper
   @Produces
   public ObjectMapper createMapper() {
       return AppConfig.getObjectMapperInstance();
   }

   public static ObjectMapper getObjectMapperInstance() {
       if (objectMapper == null) {
           objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

           //eg. configuration of Hibernate 5 - Jackson Module
           //Hibernate5Module h5m = new Hibernate5Module();
           //h5m.configure(Hibernate5Module.Feature.SERIALIZE_IDENTIFIER_FOR_LAZY_NOT_LOADED_OBJECTS, true);
           //objectMapper.registerModule((com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module) h5m);

           //eg. configuration of Joda - Jackson Module
           objectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
           objectMapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
           objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
                   .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
           objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);

           //eg. custom Jackson SimpleModule registration
           SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("PaginationModule") {
               private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
               @Override
               public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
                   context.addAbstractTypeResolver(
                           new SimpleAbstractTypeResolver().addMapping(Slice.class, SliceClientImpl.class));
                   context.addAbstractTypeResolver(
                           new SimpleAbstractTypeResolver().addMapping(Page.class, PageClientImpl.class));
               }
           };
           objectMapper.registerModule(module);

       }
       return objectMapper;
   }
   }
   ```
3. Check that your provider is registered by Jax-rs / Resteasy:

In case your jackson configuration is not registered, try adding the following lines to your context in your web.xml:

```
<context-param>

  <param-name>resteasy.providers</param-name>

  <param-value>your.package.CustomJsonProvider</param-value>

</context-param>
```

Sometimes, is required to configure as a Service Provider, adding a file  "META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers" (or in WEB-INF depending on the type of packaging you use war, ear, jar, etc.) with this content:

```
your.package.CustomJsonProvider
```

---

In another way, you can return a *String* (or a *Response* object), inject your ObjectMapper (or your utility to handle JSON format) in your Service and create/serialize your object previous the return statement.

eg. using Json-b

```
@Path("/myservice")
public class MyService {

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/resources")
    public Response createJson(@FormParam("name") String name, @FormParam("surname") String surname) {
        Response response;
        User u = new User(name, surname);
        Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();
        String jsonString = jsonb.toJson(u);
        response = Response.ok(jsonString).build();

        return response;
    }
}
```

eg. using json-b to create a custom json programmatically

```
 // Create Json and serialize    
 JsonObject json = Json.createObjectBuilder()
 .add("name", "Falco")
 .add("age", BigDecimal.valueOf(3))
 .add("biteable", Boolean.FALSE).build();    String result = json.toString();
```

eg. using Jackson to create a custom json programmatically

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ArrayNode arrayNode = mapper.createArrayNode();
    ObjectNode objectNode1 = mapper.createObjectNode();
    objectNode1.put("name", "Anna");
    objectNode1.put("surname", "T");
    arrayNode.add(objectNode1);
    ObjectNode objectNode2 = mapper.createObjectNode();
    objectNode2.put("name", "John");
    objectNode2.put("surname", "X");
    arrayNode.add(objectNode2);

    String json = arrayNode.toString();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, I do not know whether I use CDI, Jackson or Resteasy or anything else. I do not have a web.xml or other resources and I do not have dependencies in the POM besides javaee-api.

Comment: Can you provide your DTO structure and objects bad serialized? Do you have a bom imported in your pom.xml? Try to discover your json provider in debug mode with breakpoints in: https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/e82bbc2005de72858802c42aba53675c37eeea57/providers/jackson2/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/providers/jackson/ResteasyJackson2Provider.java#L206

Comment: And https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/e82bbc2005de72858802c42aba53675c37eeea57/providers/jackson/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/providers/jackson/ResteasyJacksonProvider.java#L42 or https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/e82bbc2005de72858802c42aba53675c37eeea57/providers/jettison/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/providers/jaxb/json/JsonMapProvider.java#L115

Comment: If you know your json provider you can replace it with your custom implementation. You can check Console/server log in DEBUG to check for resteasy, jackson or jettison too. If you don’t care about your current provider you can follow steps to add a new one... it will override your default implementation. Take care of add your dependencies (providers, jackson, jettison, etc) in your pom as “provided” (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6/html/development_guide/add_an_explicit_module_dependency_to_a_deployment1)

Comment: My DTO problem is an object containing various fields. One of the fields is not a string, but contains a String field itself. This field is serialized as empty {}. I just thought that it should be possible to find out the standards that Jboss uses, e.g. if giving no configuration leads to Jackson or Gson or whatever.

Comment: Because there are no boms imported, not dependencies set, nor any other configurations in the project. Not a web.xml. Nothing. Jboss runs the Rest service nevertheless.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a simplified example of both objects? Especially considering constructors, setters and getters of both related objects. I can test it in my environment and see what the problem is with your object that does not seem so complex as to require provider configurations or customized global configurations.